# tabularx+xcolor \rowcolor extends past page width

Tags: tables, pdftex, color, margins, tabularx

EDIT: I'm using this template: [PoPETs (Sciendo)](https://petsymposium.org/files/popets.zip). This is important for the failure.

Here's some simple code to demonstrate which uses the dgruyter_NEW package from the above template:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,oneside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_NEW}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\definecolor{tableheadcolor}{gray}{0.92}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l}
    \rowcolor{tableheadcolor} A \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

For reference, I am using this template: [PoPETs (Sciendo)](https://petsymposium.org/files/popets.zip). Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please post a complete example, which starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled? And explain why you put `\centering` *after* `\end{tabularx}`?

Comment: Sure, I have done so. The \centering does not seem to have affected the result, I believe it was for a caption that I removed.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that on my installation the package `dgruyter_NEW` is not known. If I replace it by `tabularx`, I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! Yep, that package comes from the conference template. I have narrowed the issue to that template itself, but I haven't gotten further.

Comment: OK, then you probably may want to provide a link to the template, maybe a good soul will dig through it. (There is a general misconception that every `.sty` file is written by a LaTeX goddess. Unfortunately this is very far from the truth, and in particular conference templates often leave a lot room for improvement.)

Comment: Yep, the link is at the bottom of the post. I'll move it up!

Comment: Off-topic: (i) using `tabularx` at least one table's column had to be `X` type of column. In your case it should be: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}`, (ii) `table*` are always on the top of the next page from the point where is inserted, so the  placement option `[t]`  is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(My answer gives the same suggestion with [@shaananc's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548722/79060), but with a complete example accompanied with some explanations.)

`dgruyter_NEW.sty` patches many internal macros including `\@array`. As @shaananc pointed, two `\expandafter\ifx\d@llarbegin\begingroup\hskip-\col@sep\fi` is added to the definition of `\@preamble`, which as I understand is used to remove the space before first column and after last column in a tabular. It seems this change is not compatible with `\rowcolor`.

In the following example, those two lines are removed from the definition of `\@array` (by `\xpatchcmd` from `xpatch` command), and tabular examples are given to illustrate what changed and how to restore the effect of `dgruyter_NEW.sty` manually.

```
\documentclass[USenglish,oneside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_NEW}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\definecolor{tableheadcolor}{gray}{0.92}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@array
  {\expandafter\ifx\d@llarbegin\begingroup\hskip-\col@sep\fi}
  {}
  {}{\fail}
\xpatchcmd\@array
  {\expandafter\ifx\d@llarbegin\begingroup\hskip-\col@sep\fi}
  {}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsection*{With \texttt{\string\rowcolor}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c}
  \rowcolor{tableheadcolor} A \\
  B \\
  C \\
\end{tabularx}

\subsection*{Without \texttt{\string\rowcolor}}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  A \\
  B \\
  C \\
\end{tabular}\smallskip

Note the space of width \verb|\tabcolsep| is inserted before first column and after last column by default (again).

\subsection*{Without \texttt{\string\rowcolor}, use \texttt{@\{\}} to remove  that space}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  A \\
  B \\
  C \\
\end{tabular}\smallskip

Note this emulates the original effect of \verb|dgruyter_NEW.sty|.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This block of code in the template is causing the issues:

```
\def\@array[#1]#2{%
  \@tempdima \ht \strutbox
  \advance \@tempdima by\extrarowheight
  \setbox \@arstrutbox \hbox{\vrule
             \@height \arraystretch \@tempdima
             \@depth \arraystretch \dp \strutbox
             \@width \z@}%
  \begingroup
  \@mkpream{#2}%
  \xdef\@preamble{\noexpand \ialign \@halignto
                  \bgroup
                    \expandafter\ifx\d@llarbegin\begingroup\hskip-\col@sep\fi
                    \@arstrut \@preamble
                    \expandafter\ifx\d@llarbegin\begingroup\hskip-\col@sep\fi
                          \tabskip \z@ \cr}%
  \endgroup
  \@arrayleft
  \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi \fi
  \bgroup
  \let \@sharp ##\let \protect \relax
  \lineskip \z@
  \baselineskip \z@
  \m@th
  \let\\\@arraycr \let\tabularnewline\\\let\par\@empty \@preamble}
```

It is used to modify the box sizes for the template, but I don't know enough to explain what the precise problem is or to provide a fix.

EDIT: My suspicion is that the lengths here aren't what they should be `\expandafter\ifx\d@llarbegin\begingroup\hskip-\col@sep\fi`